# GeoPandas clip returns empty

Tags: python, clip, geopandas

I'm trying to clip a set of polylines to a polygon with `geopandas` but it's returning an empty set. Here's my code:

```py
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

>>> gdf_lines = gpd.read_file('by_christina_nhd_0.geojson')
>>> gdf_basin = gpd.read_file('christina_proj_4269.geojson')
```

```py
>>> ax = gdf_lines.plot()
>>> gdf_basin.plot(ax=ax, color='white', linewidth=2, edgecolor='black')
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: polylines with polygon overlaid]

```py
>>> gdf_lines.crs == gdf_basin.crs
True
```

```py
>>>clipped_lines = gpd.clip(gdf_lines, gdf_basin)
>>>clipped_lines.empty
True
```

They obviously intersect, so what's up? Why isn't `clip` returning those lines within the polygon? Any ideas?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jsadler2/a493f9554829f648849f3e2af6aa8492) is a link to the geojson files

FYI - I've also tried this on QGIS and I get an empty set there too. It also has a warning about "invalid geometry." Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polygon is indeed invalid. You can check it for example with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo -sql "select isvalidreason(geometry) from christina_proj_4269" jsonpoly.json -dialect sqlite
...
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  isvalidreason(geometry) (String) = Self-intersection[-75.5297803164871 39.7081441293768]
```

The viewer in Gist actually shows the error

[image]

Fix the data and try again.

Comment: That was it! Thank you